# Set parent Visible property from child trigger

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a UserControl which I use for displaying loading animation on DataGrid. When data is found I end
animation by setting Visibility.Collapsed for UserControl.This works.

However I would like to be able to display a "No record found" message too. So I've added a TextBox into UserControl and bind It's Visibility property. When there is no data, this property hides loading animation (rectangles) and shows TextBox instead. When this happens I also added animation for TextBox.

Key part missing is how to set Usercontrol back to Visible.Collapsed once TextBox animation is over, so that I can reuse whole thing on next data searching.

My UserControl:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyProject.LoadingControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject"
             mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="100" d:DesignWidth="110">
          
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <StackPanel.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Rectangle.Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard Name="waitingAnimation" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="R1" BeginTime="0:0:0.05" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From=".1" To="1" AutoReverse="True" Duration="0:0:0.3"/>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="R2" BeginTime="0:0:0.1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From=".1" To="1" AutoReverse="True" Duration="0:0:0.3"/>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="R3" BeginTime="0:0:0.15" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From=".1" To="1" AutoReverse="True" Duration="0:0:0.3"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </StackPanel.Triggers>
                 
            <Rectangle Name="R1" Fill="#FF909595" Opacity=".1" Width="12" Height="8">
                <Rectangle.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"></Setter>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding No_records}" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Rectangle.Style>
            </Rectangle>
            <Rectangle Name="R2" Fill="#FF909595" Opacity=".1" Width="12" Height="8" Margin="2,0,0,0">
                <Rectangle.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"></Setter>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding No_records}" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Rectangle.Style>
            </Rectangle>
            <Rectangle Name="R3" Fill="#FF909595" Opacity=".1" Width="12" Height="8" Margin="2,0,0,0">
                <Rectangle.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"></Setter>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding No_records}" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Rectangle.Style>
            </Rectangle>


            <TextBox Name="txt" Text="No records found" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Segoe Print" BorderBrush="Black" Padding="3" >
                <TextBox.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                      
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
                       
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding No_records}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"></Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            
                            <Trigger Property="Visibility" Value="Visible">
                                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="1" To="0" AutoReverse="True" BeginTime="0:0:0" Duration="0:0:1" RepeatBehavior="0:0:4"/>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Duration="0:0:1" BeginTime="0:0:4.5" >
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame Value="{x:Static Visibility.Hidden}" KeyTime="0:0:1"></DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </Trigger.EnterActions>
                            </Trigger>

                        </Style.Triggers>

                    </Style>
                </TextBox.Style>
            </TextBox>
        </StackPanel>
   
</UserControl>
```

ViewModel code:

```
  private void Get_data()
  {
      //Visible property for my UserControl 
      LoadingControl_visible = Visibility.Visible;

      //Fetching data - asnyc method
      var _data = _procedures.Get_employees().Result;

      if(_data == null)
      {
         return;
      }
      else
      {
          //Set ItemsSource property
          DataGrid_data = _data;

          if (DataGrid_data.Count>0)
          {
              //Records found - hide UserControl 
              LoadingControl_visible = Visibility.Collapsed;
          }
          else
          {
             //Property for showing Textbox inside UserControl - no records found
             No_records = true;
        
          }
       }
    }
```

And Usercontrol is set in View like this:

```
 <loading_ctl:LoadingControl Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="{Binding LoadingControl_visible}"/>
```

**How can I set Visible.Collapsed to parent UserControl from child TextBox trigger?**

Comment: Set the Completed handler in the Storyboard or one of the animations (DoubleAnimation, ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames).
In the handler, perform the actions you need at the end of the animation.

Comment: Is this user control a *custom control*? Then I expect it to have dependency property to which you can bind text visibility somewhere else. General advice: look into MVVM, it will make your software architecture easier to overview and support. Imagine another guy, who has to figure out how text is being hidden by some child user control...

Comment: @EldHasp, thanks. That could actually work. Was hoping for xaml solution only, but It seems like can't be done.

Comment: @Sinatr, yes a custom control..And I am using MVVM. But I don't see how dependency property would help me in this situation. Besides that, I don't need dependency property as long as I have "No_records" property in my ViewModel- UserControl still works, because It's on same View with same DataContext.

Comment: *"I am using MVVM"* - you don't: `Get_data()` in view model operating controls directly? And another point to criticise - you are not following naming guidelines. I recommend you to set up a [code-review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) with MVVM experts to learn it better.

Comment: @Sinatr, It's my first MVVM project. I don't see why Get_data() is a problem. Data access code is separated from VM, and returned result then assigns property for DataGrid ItemsSource. So VM doesn't know about DB stuff, and View doesn't know about VM - except though DataContext. How else should I do that ? And what naming guidelines - for this site or code (Get_data is not an actual name of my method though).

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out, I solved my problem using Completed event of storyboard, in code behind:

```
public partial class LoadingControl : UserControl
{
        public LoadingControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var story=(Storyboard)this.FindResource("story");
            story.Completed += new EventHandler(Story_Completed);
        }
       
        private void Story_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
 }
```